# Differences between curlybraces and parentheses wrapping in React or JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Why in the start snippet below, the `const user` are wrapped in curly braces and the `const element` are wrapped in parentheses?

```
function formatName(user) {
  return user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;
}

const user = {
  firstName: 'Harper',
  lastName: 'Perez'
};

const element = (
  <h1>
    Hello, {formatName(user)}!
  </h1>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  element,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: becuase an object is being assigned to `const user` is an object, and the result of an expression is being assigned to `const element`.  The `()` around element is optional though.  You could also do `const user = ({
  firstName: 'Harper',
  lastName: 'Perez'
});`

Comment: jsx is an expression like 3+5 or (3+5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use:

```
const element = (
  <h1>
    Hello, {formatName(user)}!
  </h1>
);
```

You're using `JSX`, which offers a Javascript XML like language, it's like a pre-processor.

Otherwise, when you use:

```
const user = {
  firstName: 'Harper',
  lastName: 'Perez'
};
```

You're creating a plain Javascript object, where you can store data and access it like `user.firstName` or `user.lastName`.

Answer (score 2):

In first case:

```
const user = {
  firstName: 'Harper',
  lastName: 'Perez'
};
```

user is an `object` with `key: value` pairs and hence `{}`

while in second case,

```
const element = (
  <h1>
    Hello, {formatName(user)}!
  </h1>
);
```

the multiline JSX expression in wrapped within `()` to add to the readability of the code, and as [per the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx),

> It is recommend to wrap it in parentheses to avoid the pitfalls of
>   [automatic semicolon insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi).

Comment: Not entirely correct; the JSX expression is multi-line for readability, but the parentheses are to avoid automatic semicolon insertion, as stated in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx).